# stop htaccess from rewrite in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have problem with htaccess

i make convert url to html from php

but if any subfolder in domain all convert url to html

i just need domain conert url and not in any subfolder

this is my code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://%{http_host} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: and other problem is files in main folder like sitemap.xml convert to html how to stop this url from convert

Comment: any help guys :( google can not found sitemap.xml or sitemap.xml.gz :( :(

Comment: pls give us some urls examples which will describe your problems. e.g. `from`-->`to`-->`needed`

Comment: elfnoon.com/ any subfolder will convert to html

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)sitemap\.xml(.*)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^/]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://%{http_host} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thx but i have 2 file i dont want to be convert like sitemap.xml and sitemap.xml.gz

Comment: @user1653339 Then just add those to the exclusion conditions. I've added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)sitemap\.xml(.*)$` to exclude anything with `sitemap.xml` in it.

Comment: sitemap.xml.gz is redirect to error.html but sitemap.xml work fine

Comment: @user1653339 these rules won't redirect sitemap.xml.gz to anything

Comment: @user1653339 You should [click on the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that the question gets marked as answered.